# Click and CheckStateChanged VB6

Tags: vb6

According to Microsoft:
"In Visual Basic 6.0, the Click event is raised when the CheckBox state is changed programmatically. "
and this is exactly what i do not want.

I want click event only raise when i click on the checkbox and not when the state is changed.

Any idea how to do it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `Click` event code in the `MouseDown` event instead. You'll have to manually set the checkstate though:

```
Private Sub Check1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Check1.Value = IIf(Check1.Value = vbChecked, vbUnchecked, vbChecked)
    ' run other necessary code here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

you can set a flag when you are populating the form from code to ignore changes.  This can get messy if the code is not organized well.

Form Level:

```
  Public IgnoreChange As Boolean
```

Form Load:

```
  IgnoreChange = False
```

Event:

```
  If IgnoreChange Then Exit Sub
```

Your code:

```
  frmReference.IgnoreChange = True
  frmReference.Checkbox1.Checked = True
  frmReference.IgnoreChange = False
```

Code should only respond to user actions

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's the best way, but one way would be to have a variable called something like IgnoreEvents and set that to true right before changed the state programmatically.
Then in the event handler if that variable is true, you just exit the event handler without doing anything.

Comment: i have written an small procedure to run when user clicks on the checkbox, i need to add something here to say that only runs when user clicks and not when the state is changed grammatically.
Because it is almost impossible to find all places that change the state in this application

Comment: @user1162527 Unfortunately you might have to refactor the app to do that. Maybe create a `ClickButton` method that send the actual click and change all the other code to call that method rather than to send the actual clicks everywhere, that way you'd make it a little easier at least.